# Auto FIll and Submit web-page

Tags: vbscript, submit

I want to fill the web-page fields by entering some values and submit it automatically.

I tried using vbscript, all works fine, but SendKeys {"ENTER"} doesn't work when windows is locked. I want to  run the script at scheduled time. ( Which i can manage through WIN Scheduler).

Browser is IE 6 on WIN XP.

Thanks!

Comment: can you just run a POST request to the action target of the form?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Visual Basic, and not VBScript, to [automate Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167658).  If you can't make the post directly to the server (i.e. skip the browser completely and just do an HTTP post), you will have better luck using the [IE web control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234651%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in Visual Basic and navigating it's DOM.